# Badge count will not clear

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

After sending an alert through the MobilePush application to our company's app - the badge count does not decrease in value or clear. Is this something that must be handled in the development of the app itself? Or is this a feature inherent to the MobilePush application?

Comment: Did you set up a notification handler, outlined [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/push_android_code.htm)?

Comment: Unsure, I will need to confirm with my developers. Is this the same documentation for marketing cloud SDKs?

Comment: I didn't see the MC tag, so I apologize. It may be something else. I presume though that there's a similar mechanism for the MC SDK, too.

Comment: No worries I added that tag after the fact. :)

Answer (score 1):

Badge counts are sent along with the push notification from the MarketingCloud system and would be set to that value by iOS at the time the notification "arrives".

An application developer can clear the badge count via the JB4ASDK using ETPush's `-resetBadgeCount` method.

To ensure that the MarketingCloud servers know you've reset the badge, call updateET after doing so.

From the header...

/**
Reset the application's badge number to zero (aka, remove it). Call updateET to refresh the server with the current badge number. Note: updateET may not be fully processed by the server for a number of minutes; the server's badge value may be out of sync with the app for a short amount of time.

@return Doesn't return a value
 */

-(void)resetBadgeCount;